# TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined in q-ajax-bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

**Quasar: v0.17.2**

**Node: v9.4.0**

**NPM: 5.6.0**

I am manipulating ajax bar using start/stop event. And getting below error while my App.vue is getting rendered.

> Error in mounted hook: TypeError: Cannot read property $on of
>   undefined

Template:

```
<q-ajax-bar ref="loadingBar" :delay="delay" :speed="speed" :color="color" />
```

Script:

```
this.$refs.loadingBar.$on('stop', () => {
      console.log("ajax-bar stop");
    });
this.$refs.loadingBar.$on('start', () => {
       console.log("ajax-bar start");
      }
    });
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @start and @stop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked! Thank you :)